# Ruby - Find duplicates in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to write a method in Ruby that takes an array of size N and finds duplicates in the array and lists the duplicate.

I'm having trouble creating an array with a range of 0..N-2.

It tells me N is an uninitialized constant. How do I create such an array?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried writing code? We'd prefer to correct what you've written rather than write new code for you. It's easier for you to correct something than to shoehorn in new code that is totally unrelated to any code surrounding it.

Answer (score 11):

Here's one option

```
def list_duplicates(array)
  duplicates = array.select { |e| array.count(e) > 1 }
  duplicates.uniq
end
```

I tested it out here

```
 list_duplicates([1,1,4,5,6,6,9]
 => [1,6]
```

Comment: That will work but will get geometrically slower on larger arrays.

Comment: `array.count` iterates over all the elements in the array, just as `select` does, so for an array of 500K elements, this could be cripplingly slow, as it'd do 250 billion operations. A one-pass approach using `group_by` might be faster here.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use a simple counter hash:

```
def duplicate_count(array)
  array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |value, hash|
    # Keep a count of all the unique values encountered
    hash[value] += 1
  end.count do |(value,count)|
    # Compute how many have a count > 1
    count > 1
  end
end

duplicate_count([1,2,3,4])
# => 0

duplicate_count([1,2,2,3,4,4,2])
# => 2
```

If you'd prefer to return the duplicated values:

```
def duplicate_count(array)
  array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |value, hash|
    # Keep a count of all the unique values encountered
    hash[value] += 1
  end.each_with_object([ ]) do |(value,count), result|
    # Collect those with count > 1 into a result array.
    if (count > 1)
      result << value
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write following code

```
def duplicate_value(array)
  array.select{|v| array.count(v) > 1}.uniq
end

duplicate_value([1, 2, 1, 3, 3])
=> [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this, it works and I would like feedback so I'm sharing here.

```
def duplicate_array(arr)
  duplicates = []
  while arr.size != 1
    pivot = arr.shift
    arr.each do |element|
      if element.eql?(pivot)
        next if duplicates.include?(element)
        duplicates << element
      end
    end
  end
  duplicates
end
```